# Symmetric Group Acting on homocyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Let $G := \underbrace{\mathbb{Z}/p^{e}\mathbb{Z} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{Z}/p^{e}\mathbb{Z}}_{n}  = \{(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}) : a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}/p^{e}\mathbb{Z} \}$, and consider the action by $\text{Sym}(n)$ that permutes the factros. That is, for some $\sigma \in \text{Sym}(n)$,

$(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n})\sigma = (a_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,a_{\sigma(n)}).$

So $\sigma$ defines a map between $G$ and itself. I have two questions about this.

1. Is this action bijective? I believe it is but my calculations are getting me nowhere
2. Is this a homomorphism? I also have a feeling that it is. If this is true, does this mean that $\text{Sym}(n) \leq \text{Aut}(G)$?

Comment: The answer to all of your questions is yes. But you should really stick to right actions or to left actions. Using left actions, the correct definition is $\sigma(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = (a_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\ldots,a_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DerekHolt . I am told that $ \text{Sym}(n) \leq Aut(\{(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n-1} : a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}/p^{e}\mathbb{Z} \})$ by acting on a subgroup of G such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} = 0$, but i dont quite understand this. Would you happen to know anything about this?